# call of method inside component gets answered by the root instead

Tags: javascript, components, vue.js

I'm creating a modal, which is defined as a component.
The component has a method "set_pdf_form('x')" to change one of it's data variables to x and in the component template there is a @click which calls this method.
But the method in the component doesn't answer the call. Instead, if I put the method in the root, it responds to the call.

the modal.js

```
Vue.component('modal', {
    template: '#modal-template',
    props: ['show'],

    methods: {
        set_pdf_form (f) {
            this.selected_pdf_form = f;
            console.log('i never get called');
        },
        close () {
            this.show = false;
        }
    },

    data () {
        return {
            selected_pdf_form: 't'
        }
    }
});
```

the root.js (VUE 1.0.26)

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    methods: {
        set_pdf_form (f) {
            console.log('why do i respond to the call of the component?');
        }
});
```

and the template

```
<modal v-ref:pdf>
    <h3 slot="header">PDF</h3>
    <div slot="body">
        <form slot="form" id="modalform" action="pdf/controller>/123" target="_blank" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <p slot="body" class="outputformat">
                <a @click.prevent="set_pdf_form('one')"><img src="lay/output_one.svg"></a>
                <a @click.prevent="set_pdf_form('two')"><img src="lay/output_two.svg"></a>
                <a @click.prevent="set_pdf_form('three')"><img src="lay/output_three.svg"></a>
            </p>
            <div class="modal-buttons">
                <button class="cancel" @click.prevent="closeModal('pdf')">cancel</button>
                <button class="go" @click="closeModal('pdf')">go</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</modal>
```

I thought that since every component instance has its own isolated scope, the @click should call the method of the modal instance. I don't understand why it's the root method that responds to the call.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register in root component and make it  `inline-template`

See the code.. http://www.webpackbin.com/4koPpp92Z

This is explained in http://vuejs-ru.github.io/vuejs.org/guide/best-practices.html (search for `inline-template`)

Comment: thanks, your code obviously does the trick, but
- the russian doc-site you are linking to is different from the docs on vuejs.org, and i'm not quite sure what to think of that

Comment: anyway it seems odd to me that i have to inline-template a component to get it to use its own scope
- when i insert the "inline-template" and the "components"-part it breaks my code
- and most of all: i have a dozen other components in my app which behave exactly as one would think, namely within their own scope; i don't get it why this modal component is different

Comment: See the english docs.. https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Inline-Template.   "makes the component’s template compilation un-cachable." Maybe your problem is that this component is cached

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the compilation scope of slot content. Anything referenced inside slot content will be at the scope where the content is, not the child component.

Given html such as:

```
<my-component>
  <a @click="doSomething()">Do something</a>
</my-component>
```

`doSomething` will need to exist on the parent Vue instance, not inside the `my-component` Vue instance.

See the docs at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Compilation-Scope

I suspect the components which you have working are not using slots?

#### One possible solution

It's possible to use [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots) to pass a `this` reference from the the child component to the component consumer. This gives the consumer access to any methods defined on the component.

Example `dog` component template:

```
<template>
      <slot :thisDog="this"></slot>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      bark() {
        console.log("bark!");
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Example consuming markup:

```
<dog>
  <template scope="props">
    <a href="#" @click="props.thisDog.bark()">Click me</a>
  </template>
</dog>
```